# Ionic3 - Import modules into main app module - then inject them into services/components

Tags: angular, import, module, inject

If I import `HttpClientModule` in `app.module.ts`:

```
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
```

and inject it into `@NgModule` of application:

```js
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    MyApp
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    IonicModule.forRoot(MyApp)
  ],
  bootstrap: [IonicApp],
  entryComponents: [
    MyApp
  ],
  providers: [
    StatusBar,
    SplashScreen,
    {provide: ErrorHandler, useClass: IonicErrorHandler}
  ]
})
```

How can I reuse it in other pages, components etc? Should I import it again or can somehow inject it from main application module?

Answer (score 0):

If you inject it in the main module i.e `app.module.ts` file then no need to inject anywhere else in the application.

You just need to import `httpClient` when you have to use in your service or component.

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
```